# UILabel not animated at the end

Tags: swift

I have an array of UITextField and with 2 UIButtons, I can add or remove one.When I click the button, the movements are animated with the method UIView.animated() and the label under it works as well, but when I delete the last textField,the label is not animated.I put a gif to figure out what I mean.

[image]

This is the code:

```
let lastItem = newRecipeModel.textField[index]

        newRecipeModel.textField.remove(at: index)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

            lastItem.alpha = 0

            if index>0{
                self.newRecipeView.directives.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.newRecipeModel.textField[index-1].bottomAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
                self.newRecipeView.directives.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.newRecipeView.ingredientsTextField.leftAnchor).isActive = true
            }else if index == 0{
                self.newRecipeView.directives.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.newRecipeView.ingredientsTextField.bottomAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
                self.newRecipeView.directives.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.newRecipeView.ingredientsTextField.leftAnchor).isActive = true
            }

            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

            }, completion: { (true) in

                lastItem.removeFromSuperview()
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
```

Comment: did you ever find a solution? Running into something similar myself.

Comment: @Kyle I think the problem was about the constraints. You have to try modify them and execute layoutIfNeeded() at the end.